# How to check number of emails sent by Symfony in Codeception unit test

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, codeception

I can test for the number of emails sent in a **functional** test, but I haven't been able to test for the number of emails sent in a **unit** test.

I'm testing a Command that sends different numbers of emails depending on the test setup.

When I use:

```php
  // tests
  public function testShouldSendATestEmailWhenNoParametersArePassedIn() {
    $this->assertSame('Success! (Provisionally, as long as no errors follow.)' . PHP_EOL, static::run_verify_send_email_command());
    $this->tester->seeEmailIsSent(3);
  }
```

I get the following error:

```
[TypeError] Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profiler::loadProfileFromResponse() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, null given
```

If I comment out `$this->tester->seeEmailIsSent(3);` the test runs and covers the appropriate code.

The Profiler seems to only be a functional test thing (i.e. using HTTP, not the command line), not a unit test thing. How can I test for the number of emails sent by a Symfony Command in a unit test?

Comment: imho unit tests by definition only test a unit, which is the smallest structure in your code, i.e. usually a class or even just a function in a class. if you have environments, responses, services, commands in a unit test, you're expecting something you shouldn't expect. why is a functional test "too much", especially since it apparently works in a functional test ... why does it need to be a unit test? you could mock the mailer and not actually send emails.

Comment: @Jakumi I don't care about "pure" unit tests, just tests that add value and detect breaking changes. Otherwise, I could never test any method that calls other methods, because it's no longer testing "a unit, which is the smallest structure in your code". The reason why it can't be a functional test (as far as I know) is because functional tests mock the HTTP service, and commands run only from the command line. There's no way to run this command via HTTP by design.

Comment: Based on that error, you are using an old version of Symfony module, upgrade codeception/module-symfony to 1.6.0 or 2.0.5, they don't have dependency on Profiler.

Comment: Thanks @Naktibalda! I'm in the process of upgrading Symfony (currently on 4.0) although Codeception is on the latest version. Do you know what the minimum version of Symfony is required for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the code again and realized that upgrading codeception/module-symfony won't help. `seeEmailIsSent` only works if simulated HTTP request was made by test.

Correct approach in unit test is to inject a mock of mailer class to the class or function that you are testing.

```
public function testEmailIsSent()
{
  $mailerMock = $this->createMock(\Symfony\Component\Mailer::class);
  $mailerMock->expect($this->once())->method('send');

  $testInstance = new MyClass($mailerMock);
  $testInstance->toSomething();
}
```

Read more information about mocks at https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html

Comment: I tried swapping out the default mailer for the mock mailer (in Symfony's test container), but it's still using the default mailer in the test. My class is a command. It calls other things which eventually call the mailer. It doesn't use the mailer directly, but testing it is pretty useless if I can't count how many emails were sent (by a single `send` call, so counting the calls wouldn't tell me how many emails were sent anyway). Can I tell Symfony to inject my mock mailer instead of its default test mailer?